# Does the site do article pinning?

Tags: discussion

Are there particular questions that are generic where we can pin it and call it done?  For instance, the question of howto break in a motorcycle engine came up.  I typed in a bunch of words but the expectation that my opinion on the subject will be generally agreed upon is unrealistic and defending an opinion on the subject, if I needed to have a debate, would be somewhat worthless.

My point being, lots of opinion, lots of variance on the subject...can an article be written sharing all of the opinions and then just call it done?

Here's the break in question I referenced.  [Royal Enfield Classic 350 - Motor Break-in Best Practice](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/15596/royal-enfield-classic-350-motor-break-in-best-practice/15627?noredirect=1#comment21066_15627)

Comment: I would only hope there could be ... I guess it could come under the community wiki answers or some such. Also, I've tried in the past to get a blog going, which would also allow for this type of pinned (or at a minimum, easy to find) answers to many common questions. I thought your answer to the Royal Enfield question was good ... I hope it doesn't get lost in the shuffle.